# Are devices damaged by high current, or high temperature?

Tags: voltage, current, integrated-circuit, temperature

I'm wondering if electrical devices are damaged by the current or by the temperature. Imagine we have a little device with a maximum input current of 500mA. I'm sure that if we subject it to 1A or 4A it will become very hot and probably explode. The question I'm asking is whether the high temperature induced by the current is the principal cause or it's the high amount of current that is the cause. I'm wondering if we cooled the device at -230 Celsius (we're accepting that it's still working) and then we applied that high amount of current would it survive?

Comment: The explosion of a device would happen when it turn into a chain reaction or exponential growth of it's production of heat. yes you are right there is always a threshold to reach that point. That threshold point is a function of time, current, and temperature. They are modeling using computer simulations.

Comment: Related: [What exactly gets “worn out” and damaged by heat?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/96049/17608)

Comment: @PhilFrost I think he is mentioning about the critical point of the system.

Answer (score 2):

First, many devices specify a maximum input current as a characteristic, rather than an operating requrement. For example, if a digital logic IC specifies its maximum input current is 5 mA (for example), that usually means that as long as you provide an appropriate power supply voltage, the device will not draw more than 5 mA --- that is, it is the device's promise not to take more than 5 mA, not a requirement to the user not to provide more than 5 mA.

However, other devices do specify a current limit as a user requirement. Common examples are resistors, inductors, linear regulators. For resistors or linear regulators, the reason for this limit is usually to limit self-heating that would cause thermal damage to the part. For inductors, the limit is more often related to saturation of the core material, although thermal limts can also come into play. In these cases, providing better cooling (say by heatsinking) can allow operating with higher currents, or be required to avoid de-rating the max current specs.

> I'm wondering if we cooled the device at -230 Celsius (we're accepting that it's still working) and then we applied that high amount of current would it survive?

It depends on the type of part. For some parts, it might allow you to operate with higher-than-rated currents. In other parts it might cause thermal stresses (due to thermal gradients and or CTE mismatch between different materials within the part) that damage the part even when operated below the nominal rating.

Answer (score 1):

As a gross oversimplification, two things kill electronics: overvoltage, and overtemperature. Overcurrent can lead to either, depending on the device and the situation. So yes, some (not all!) devices could be run beyond their nominal rated currents if they were appropriately cooled. Typically, these devices would state a rated current *at some temperature*. But the details will vary greatly from device to device, and you really need to understand more about the device you're working on and what you're trying to do with it before actually proceeding with a design based around supercooling the device.

Also, it's worth pointing out that all devices have a *minimum* operational temperature (whether stated or not), meaning there's a limit to how hard you can chill them before you risk something else going wrong. And even if you could keep the case of a device near absolute zero by sinking it to a giant fractal superconductor in interstellar space, there's still the thermal drop between the innards and the case to contend with. There are hard limits to what can be achieved by chilling a given device, and the cost of a larger device is typically far less than the cost of refrigeration.

Comment: Arguably, many overvoltage faults result in dielectric breakdown, resulting in low resistance where there should be a high resistance, resulting in high currents, resulting in overtemperature. So by an even grosser oversimplification, there's only one thing that kills electronics.

Comment: Yes. Also, everyone dies of cardiac arrest.

Answer (score 0):

Devices are damaged by the first thing that kills them.

Given a sufficiently extreme over-parameter event, all devices will die.

Typically the parameters that occur around a device will be coupled by the type of the device, such that one parameter is always going to cause its demise.

For instance, take a resistor, where a voltage is applied at ambient temperature, and a current flows, heating it up. With a very low value resistor, the voltage and hence power will be low, so it may be electromigration in the conductor that eventually causes its failure. With a very high value resistor, the current and hence power will be low, and so arcing across the resistive element might be the cause of death. With a middling value, neither voltage nor current failure may occur before the resistor overheats. Obviously gross overheating takes time, whereas an arc-over can happen almost instantaneously, so time to failure is important as well.

And that's just a simple resistor. When the device is more complex, with bond wires to a semiconductor die that may fuse under pulse conditions, or thin oxide layers that may punch through with single-digit volts applied across them, or an array of small FET dice directly paralleled into a large FET whose ability to share current stably depends on the length of the heating pulse, then you have a significant job to understand the detail of all possible failure mechanisms, and which will trash the device first.